# powershell's select-string not returning results

Tags: powershell

I am trying find a specific word (Gate) in a document with powershell's select-string, and its not returning any result.

```
Get-ChildItem -path '.\somedocument.docx' | Select-String -pattern 'Gate'
```

What am I doing wrong? I am in the beginning phase of learning powershell.

Comment: Get-ChildItem just gets the file, not it's contents. Also, docx is basically a zip file with a bunch of metadata files in it. I don't think there is an easy way for PowerShell to read them and do what you want.

Comment: Thank you  CConard96. You are right. In general, it doesn't seem like there is an easy way to do anything with powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to the PoSH world. It is really important the you get some guidance / training first, to prevent you from getting lost / frustrated. See this discussion.

> Help with teaching PowerShell Learning PowerShell
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7oir35/help_with_teaching_others_powershell

CConard96 is correct on Get-Children, you read files using Get-Content or the .Net file libraries.

PowerShell has full access to any .Net library, COM and DOM interface Windows provides.

So, you need to know and use the right toolset. For what you are after, I'd not look to Select-String for this use case.

You can use PoSH to do this, but you also have to use the Word DOM.
For example:

```
# Instantiate Word object
$wd = New-Object -com word.application

# Oepn a Word doc
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open('D:\Documents\Microsoft Graph API.docx')

# Read all the doc contents
$doc.Range().text


Microsoft Graph APIList windowsInformationProtectionAppLearningSummariesImportant: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applicatio
ns is not supported.Note: Using the Microsoft Graph APIs to configure Intune controls and policies still requires that the Intune service is correctly licensed by the customer.https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/g
raph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_wip_windowsinformationprotectionapplearningsummary_list https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33525.an-introduction-to-microsoft-graph-api.aspx Using the
 Microsoft Graph API to access data in Microsoft Intunehttps://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/intunesupport/2016/10/04/using-the-microsoft-graph-api-to-access-data-in-microsoft-intune How to use Microsoft Graph and Off
ice 365 API in a Service or in a Windows App/UWP without a graphical interfacehttps://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2016/02/12/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-api-in-a-service-or-in-a-windows-appuwp-wi
thout-a-graphical-interface 


# Get formatted text
$doc.Range().paragraphs | foreach {$_.range.text}

List windowsInformationProtectionAppLearningSummaries
Important: APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are in preview and are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Note: Using the Microsoft Graph APIs to configure Intune controls and policies still requires that the Intune service is correctly licensed by the customer.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_wip_windowsinformationprotectionapplearningsummary_list 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33525.an-introduction-to-microsoft-graph-api.aspx 

Using the Microsoft Graph API to access data in Microsoft Intune
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/intunesupport/2016/10/04/using-the-microsoft-graph-api-to-access-data-in-microsoft-intune 

How to use Microsoft Graph and Office 365 API in a Service or in a Windows App/UWP without a graphical interface
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/laurelle/2016/02/12/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-and-office-365-api-in-a-service-or-in-a-windows-appuwp-without-a-graphical-interface 


# Find a specific word(s) in the Doc file, for example Graph or under or licensed using the .Net Regualr Expression namespace
[regex]::Matches(($doc.Range().text),'Graph|under|licensed').value

Graph
under
Graph
Graph
licensed
Graph
Graph

$wd.quit()
```

You won't need all of the above as I have it to solve you use case, as it can be streamlined. Yet, you see, it can be done.

There are other examples directly on this forum.

> Getting specific data out of a word document
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/38dcm7/getting_specific_data_out_of_a_word_document

You can even convert the doc to another file type then read it with the cmdlets, but that is just extra work. Why do that if you don't have to.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, postanote, but life is too short to be wasted on powershell. I've already  discovered much simpler BASH with its grep and other functions.Thank you though.

Comment: No worries.. There are lots of ways to do X or Y with any tool / tools. You have to choose what works for you based on time, skill and investment. But, unless you are looking at using the GUI only, PoSH is no a waste. Much of Windows stack, especially, cloud, and  more, requires it.